# Spinner not getting populated with the given string array

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-source, android-spinner

I have to make an android app. It is about counting Bunks for college students.
So I want to make it like this:

Spinner 1 has

Select Branch

1. ME
2. CE
3. IT
4. EE

Select semester

1st
2nd
3rd
4th

etc.

Now if student is selecting ME and 3rd semester, then his 3rd semester Subjects should come
like:

Enter Bunks of Subject:

ABC1: EditText
ABC2: EditText
ABC3: EditText
ABC4: EditText
ABC4: EditText

and this input by user should come to logic of percentage of attendance, and answers should come on another page with same subject name.

Can anyone help me please?

***EDIT***

My **Main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello" />
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want how to make and populate a spinner??...and depending on the item selected on the spinner show respective forms...if so, i can paste the code i am using for my app

Comment: please give more information so someone can help you.

Comment: This is your assignment for marks, and you're just asking other people to do it? Start the project, work on it yourself, and come back with specific questions that show you've tried to learn on your own.

Comment: NONO .. m not asking for readymade codes .. i want Help.. I am new here... 

See what i ve done until now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML for spinner:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/city_spinner_iWant"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:prompt="@string/citySpinner"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

in code, set the adapter to populate the spinner with requires items (in your case branches):

```
String[] city_array = new String[]{"London", "Newyork", "Paris"};

ArrayAdapter<String> cityArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,city_array);

city_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner_iWant);
city_spinner.setAdapter(cityArrayAdapter);
```

Then to show forms depending on the item selected in the spinner:

```
city_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,int i, long lng) {

selected_city = adapter.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected_city, 1000).show();

//conditions depending on selected_city (in your case selected branch)
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

//no need to impement this
}
});
```

Comment: yes ive done the same.. took paths as  string array..
can you please tell me how to post my code here? so can show you! 
its showing me no charcter left

Comment: how to add options? in spinner

Comment: click edit under your question ----> paste the code ----> select it and press Ctrl+k ----> save changes

Comment: what do you mean by options??

Comment: My Main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    

</LinearLayout>

Comment: I mean that string "London, Newyork, Paris" its not showing in spinner

Comment: Sir can u please see this 

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kSGDgP5vndeTJwaFprQ1dOcEE/edit

goto file and download

Comment: Yes adapter & all.. but its showing me error.. please download that file.. its done by me

Comment: or atleast the log cat....what error exactly is it??....null pointer exception or something like that

Comment: look, i don't know what your code is, but i just tried the code i pasted....and it worked as expected